# Is it possible to check the html tag name on which it is present after getting the element using test id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, testing-library

Suppose I have this code in my component.tsx file. Is there a possibility to check the tag name on which a paricular test id is present ?

```
<section>
  <h1 data-testid="page-header">
    Welcome!
  </h1>
  <Link data-testid="about-page-link" to="/about">
    Go to about
  </Link>
</section>
```

I have the following code to get the element by test id in my test file.

```
const headerElement = screen.getByTestId('page-header');
```

Is it possible to check if the following tag is present on an h1 tag ?

in short i need to check whether `page-header` test id is present on `h1` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query by data attribute directly and check the length of the returned NodeList.

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1[data-testid='page-header']");

// or if you just want the first/only H1 with the relevant attribute
document.querySelector("h1[data-testid='page-header']");
```

```js
const idToSearch = 'page-header';
const testIds = document.querySelectorAll(`h1[data-testid='${idToSearch}']`)

console.log(!!testIds.length);
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 data-testid="page-header">
    Welcome!
  </h1>
  <Link data-testid="about-page-link" to="/about"> Go to about
  </Link>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can get the single HTML `h1` element with `data-testid` as

```js
const element = document.querySelector("h1[data-testid]")
if (element && element.dataset.testid === "page-header") {
  console.log("Yeah it is present");
} else {
  console.log("Nope it's not there");
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 data-testid="page-header">
    Welcome!
  </h1>
  <Link data-testid="about-page-link" to="/about"> Go to about
  </Link>
</section>
```

You can get all `h1` headings and get their `data-testid` attribute and then match it

```js
const allHeading = [...document.querySelectorAll("h1")]
const idToSearch = "page-header";

const result = allHeading.some(heading => {
  const testId = heading.dataset.testid;
  return testId === idToSearch;
})
console.log(result);
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 data-testid="page-header">
    Welcome!
  </h1>
  <Link data-testid="about-page-link" to="/about"> Go to about
  </Link>
</section>
```